# A notation problem of partial derivatives

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

I have a notational problem of partial derivatives:

Let $z=f(x,\phi(x))$,and let $\phi(x),f$ be a differentiable functions.What is the difference between $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?In my eye,they ought to have no difference,but in my text book,the author writes:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi(x)}\frac{\partial \phi(x)}{\partial x}.$$

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: Note that $z$ and $\frac{dz}{dx}$ are functions that take a single number as input, whereas $f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ are functions that take two numbers as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Abuse of notation. You have a function $f(u,v)$ of two real (for the sake of argument) variables. You also have a function $\Phi$ of one real variable with values in $\mathbb{R}^2$, namely $\Phi(x) = (x,\phi(x))$.

Then you define $z = f \circ \Phi$. And the chain rule yields

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(\Phi(x))\cdot \frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial x}(x) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(\Phi(x))\cdot \frac{\partial \Phi_2}{\partial x}(x).$$

Now note that $\Phi_1(x) = x$, hence $\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial x} \equiv 1$, and $\Phi_2(x) = \phi(x)$, so what remains is

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}(x,\phi(x)) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(x,\phi(x))\cdot \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x).$$

Then commit the abomination of writing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi(x)}$ for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$.